# SQLite query - filter name where each associated id is contained within a set of ids

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I'm trying to work out a query that will find me all of the distinct `Names` whose `LocationIDs` are in a given set of ids. The catch is if any of the `LocationIDs` associated with a distinct `Name` are not in the set, then the `Name` should not be in the results.

Say I have the following table:

```
ID | LocationID | ... | Name
-----------------------------
1  |  1         | ... | A
2  |  1         | ... | B
3  |  2         | ... | B
```

I'm needing a query similar to

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table WHERE LocationID IN (1, 2);
```

The problem with the above is it's just checking if the `LocationID` is 1 OR 2, this would return the following:

```
A
B
```

But what I need it to return is

```
B
```

Since B is the only `Name` where both of its `LocationIDs` are in the set (1, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write two subquery.

1. get `count` by each `Name`
2. get `count` by your condition.

then `join` them by count amount, which means your need to all match your condition count number.

**Schema (SQLite v3.17)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ID int,
   LocationID int,
   Name varchar(5)

);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 1,'A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2, 1,'B');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 2,'B');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t2.Name
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LocationID) cnt
    FROM T
    WHERE LocationID IN (1, 2)
) t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LocationID) cnt,Name
    FROM T
    WHERE LocationID IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY Name
) t2 on t1.cnt = t2.cnt;

| Name |
| ---- |
| B    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sswND35ZvSb482v7dNQTi5/0)

Comment: Hey, I was just trying it out. It doesn't look like it works for other data sets. Trying it out with actual data returned the wrong results. I added more variety to the data in the fiddle and it returned a name that wasn't in the ID set. I updated the fiddle with a different data set: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sswND35ZvSb482v7dNQTi5/2 I think we're on the right track for a correct solution but I think comparing by count this way is throwing it off.

Comment: @Programmer001 Ok I see did you want to get emty result from your sample data in the sqlfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sswND35ZvSb482v7dNQTi5/3?

Comment: My bad, I added INSERT INTO T VALUES (8, 4, 'A1'); to the schema. This appears to be working. I'm going to keep playing around with it, if nothing pops up then later tomorrow I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use aggregation.  Assuming no duplicates in your table:

```
SELECT Name
FROM table
WHERE LocationID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If `Name`/`LocationID` pairs can be duplicated, use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LocationID) = 2`.